# Multiple conditional data adjustments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
                                    Species Status     T1     T2  T3
0                                  Kentucky      L   96.0   88.0  79.0
1                                    Eupesu      L    0.0    2.0   3.0
2                                  Serrated      L    1.0    4.0   2.0
3                              Smooth_Brome      L    2.0    0.0   1.0
4                                        U1      L    3.0    6.0  10.0
Total                                               102.0  100.0  95.0
```

I want to write a statement or function that says if the total for `T1` (which is 102.0) is less than 100 then take 100 - the total value within `T1` and add that value to the maximum value.  If `T1` is greater than 100 then take the total value of `T1` and subtract it from 100 and subtract that value from the maximum within `T1`.  I want to do the same thing with the total for `T2` and `T3` as well.  Essentially the total for every column should be 100.

I have been trying to do it with this code:

```
if df.T1.Total < 100:
    df.T1.max()=(100-df.T1.Total)+df.T1.max()
if  df.T1.Total > 100: 
    df.T1.max()= df.T1.max()-(df.T1.Total-100) 
if df.T2.Total < 100:
    df.T2.max()=(100-df.T2.Total)+df.T2.max()
if  df.T2.Total > 100: 
    df.T2.max()=df.T2.max()-(df.T2.Total-100)
if df.T3.Total < 100:
    df.T3.max()=(100-df.T3.Total)+df.T3.max()
if  df.T3.Total > 100: 
    df.T3.max()=df.T3.max()-(df.T3.Total-100)
df.loc['Total']=df.sum()
print df
```

and my desired output would be this:

```
                                    Species Status     T1     T2  T3
0                                  Kentucky      L   94.0   88.0  84.0
1                                    Eupesu      L    0.0    2.0   3.0
2                                  Serrated      L    1.0    4.0   2.0
3                              Smooth_Brome      L    2.0    0.0   1.0
4                                        U1      L    3.0    6.0  10.0
Total                                               100.0  100.0  100.0
```

that code though returns:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

and I am pretty sure there is a better way to do this in the first place.

Comment: Are you always adding and subtracting from Kentucky?

Comment: No, but its already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can adjust the values:

```
df = df.drop('Total').set_index(['Species', 'Status']) # recreating 'Total' and leaving only numerical columns
difference = 100 - df.sum() # adjustment values
for col, index in df.idxmax().items(): # works also if max() occurs in different rows
    df.loc[index, col] += difference[col] # adjusting each max value
```

to get:

```
Species      Status                  
Kentucky     L       94.0  88.0  84.0
Eupesu       L        0.0   2.0   3.0
Serrated     L        1.0   4.0   2.0
Smooth_Brome L        2.0   0.0   1.0
U1           L        3.0   6.0  10.0
```

so that:

```
result = pd.concat([df.reset_index(), df.sum().to_frame().T]).fillna('')
result.index = result.index.tolist()[:-1] + ['Total']
```

yields:

```
            Species Status     T1     T2     T3
0          Kentucky      L   94.0   88.0   84.0
1            Eupesu      L    0.0    2.0    3.0
2          Serrated      L    1.0    4.0    2.0
3      Smooth_Brome      L    2.0    0.0    1.0
4                U1      L    3.0    6.0   10.0
Total                       100.0  100.0  100.0
```

Comment: this returned, `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'items'` on this line `for col, index in df.idxmax().items():
        df.loc[index, col] += difference[col]`

Comment: That's odd, just using the basic `pandas` `.drop()` function here. What does `df.info()` show before you start? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: when  you changed it to`df.drop` it works fine, `pd.drop` didn't work.  I updated that comment

Comment: There is still the attribute error I listed in my previous comment

Comment: That may be a version issue, I'm using `python 3.5` & `pandas 0.18.1`. Try `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`.

Comment: Yep, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the .loc method on your dataframe:

```
if df.T1.sum() > 1:
    df.loc[df.T1 == df.T1.max(),'T1'] = df.T1.max()+df.T1.sum()
...
```